# How to Merge data frames only if a row of the first one is equal to the other one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm just trying to input in the base_consolidada df data only if the row value of the data_final in the column "Número da conta" is equal to the row in the same column name of the first df.However, it is taking too long and I don't know how to solve it....

```
for _,row in base_consolidada.iterrows():
for _,row2 in data_final.iterrows():
    if row["Número da conta"]==row2["Número da conta"]:
        row[["Investimento(DF)","Saldo Líquido(DF)","%Rend(DF)"]]=row2[["Investimento","Saldo Líquido","% Rend"]]
```

Comment: how big are your two dataframes?  You have len(df1) * len(df2) comparisons going on here, as you are comparing every row in base_consalidada individuall to every row in data_final.  Presuming that numero de conta means account number, and that each row has a unique account number, you would do better to create a set of the account numbers in each dataframe, and then an intersection of the two sets, and then look for the account numbers only in that intersection and do operations on that https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/intersection

Comment: if you had an example data set to work with, it would make it easier to help with some sample code

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague without an example. I suppose you are looking for concatenation instead of merge. try this code:

```
df_1 = base_consolidada.["Investimento(DF)","Saldo Líquido(DF)","%Rend(DF)"]
df_2 = data_final["Investimento(DF)","Saldo Líquido(DF)","%Rend(DF)"]

if base_consolidada["Número da conta"].equals(data_final["Número da conta"]):
    pd.concat([df_1, df_2])
```

Comment: All right
First of all thanks, I'll try to clarify what I want


in the base_consolidada df I have 4 columns named "Número da conta","Investimento(DF)","Saldo Líquido(DF)","%Rend(DF)"